# Does Azure Batch service has limitation on max size of docker image allowed to run?

Tags: azure-batch

We want to run a data science model using docker images in Azure batch service.
Our docker image size is 20 GB to 25 GB. Can it be run on Azure batch service?

Answer (score 1):

It depends. *Currently*, Azure Batch, *by default using standard image configurations*:

On Linux, maps container images on disk to the local temporary disk (or resource disk) with the `azure-batch` published container images. The selected VM Size and its local disk size and free space, would determine if your image would fit. Note that all task data would reside on this disk as well.

On Windows, maps container images (unmodified) to the OS disk. The size and free space of the OS disk would determine if your image would fit or not.

Generally speaking, a container image of that size is unwieldy and you would incur very large costs in not only distribution time for non-trivial pool sizes, but also unpack time.